# How do I extract space separated floating numbers from string into another array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, space, cs50

I have this code. The user should input something like this "10.0 10.0 4.0 7.0". And, I want my program to put these floating point numbers into an array so that each of these is accessible through **floats[0] = 10.0, floats[1] = 10.0  floats[2] = 4.0 floats[3] = 7.0**. I would make them floating point types later. In this code I'm trying to use two-dimensional array, but something is definitely wrong.

**Can you put me on the right track?**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{   
    // prompt the user to enter two inputs 
    string input1 = get_string();

    // declare and initialize essential variables
    int len1 = strlen(input1);
    int j = 0;

    // declare an array where the next lines of code should put floats separately
    string floats[100][100];

    // put each floating point number into an array character by character
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        if (isspace(input1[i])) {
            j++;
        } else {
            floats[j][i] = input1[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `floats[j][i]` : use other variable instead of `i`. or use `strtok` and `strcpy`.

Comment: Just FYI. If this is for the CS50x Coding Contest, you really shouldn't be soliciting outside help.  Not much of a contest if someone else solves it for you.

Comment: I'm not really aiming to win this contest, I'm in just for experience. `strtod()` was beyond my knowledge, I've never used it and couldn't find it online. So, I would never ever be able to solve this without people's help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtod()` is the best tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645334/2410359) for parsing floating point numbers.

To separate sub-strings using whitespace, at a minimum OP's code is not appending a needed null character.  Further the copying from `input1[]` needs to copy more than just one character.

```
// Avoid magic numbers, using define self-documents the code
#define FLOAT_STRING_SIZE 100
#define FLOAT_STRING_N 100

int main(void) {   
  string floats[FLOAT_STRING_N][FLOAT_STRING_SIZE];
  string input1 = get_string();
  char *p = input1;

  int count;
  for (count = 0; count < FLOAT_STRING_N; count++) {
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *p) p++;

    // no more
    if (*p == '\0') break; 

    int i;            
    for (i = 0; i<FLOAT_STRING_SIZE-1; i++) {
      if (isspace((unsigned char) *p) || *p == '\0') break;
      floats[count][i] = *p++;  // save character and advance to next one.
    }
    floats[count][i] = '\0';
  }

  int count;
  for (int c = 0; c < count; c++) {
    puts(floats[c]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringstream (although that's a c++ way) like this

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str (input1);
int i = 0;
string t;
while ( ss >> t) 
{
     floats[i++] = std::stof(t); //fill your array one by one
}
```

For pure C way, you can use sscanf.

Comment: For a C question, the C solution should not be an afterthought.

Comment: This person is using cs50 (yuck), meaning they're taking a cradle *beginning* C course. An answer in a different language probably isn't going to help much, especially one that isn't explained in detail.

Comment: I was going to put a note about the same in my post. Saying that OP is using 'string' in his program already, so it's not pure C anyways. If he was using char* instead, I'd have only mentioned sscanf

Comment: From `cs50.h`, `string` *is* `char*`. Thus my prior comment concerning that header (yuck). Hiding pointer types in aliases rarely brings clarity to *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtod()` to parse the string one floating point number at a time:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {   
    // prompt the user to enter two inputs 
    char *input1 = get_string();

    // declare the destination array for the floating point numbers
    double numbers[100];
    int n;

    char *p = input1;
    char *q;

    for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        numbers[n] = strtod(p, &q);
        if (p == q) {
            // no more numbers to parse
            break;
        }
        p = q;
    }

    // print the array contents
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```